# Distinguish between NULL and FALSE with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, null, phpunit

Does anyone know a reliable way to distinguish between FALSE and NULL with PHPUnit?

I'm trying to distinguish from NULL and FALSE in return values in my assertions.

This fails:

```
$this->assertNotEquals(FALSE, NULL);
```

And these assertions pass:

```
$this->assertFalse(NULL);
$this->assertNull(FALSE);
```

Edit: For some context, this is to distinguish between an error state (FALSE) versus an empty result (NULL). To ensure the function is returning properly, I need to distinguish between the two. 
Thanks

Edit...
As per some of the problems regarding what I am testing, I'm adding the tests.

```
Class testNullFalse extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{


    public function test_null_not_false (){
      $this->assertNotEquals(FALSE, NULL, "False and null are not the same");
    }

    public function test_null_is_false (){
      $this->assertFalse(NULL, "Null is clearly not FALSE");
    }

    public function test_false_is_null (){
      $this->assertNull(FALSE, "False is clearly not NULL");
    }

    public function test_false_equals_null(){
      $this->assertEquals(FALSE, NULL, "False and null are not equal");
    }

    public function test_false_sameas_null(){
      $this->assertSame(FALSE, NULL, "False and null are not the same");
    }

    public function test_false_not_sameas_null(){
      $this->assertNotSame(FALSE, NULL, "False and null are not the same");
    }
}
```

And the results.

```
PHPUnit 3.5.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

FFF.F.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.50Mb

There were 4 failures:

1) testNullFalse::test_null_not_false
False and null are not the same
Failed asserting that <null> is not equal to <boolean:false>.

2) testNullFalse::test_null_is_false
Null is clearly not FALSE
Failed asserting that <null> is false.

3) testNullFalse::test_false_is_null
False is clearly not NULL
Failed asserting that <boolean:false> is null.

4) testNullFalse::test_false_sameas_null
False and null are not the same
<null> does not match expected type "boolean".

FAILURES!
Tests: 6, Assertions: 6, Failures: 4.
```

Comment: PHPunit (at least v3.7+, if not before) now has assertSame() which checks if the two variables have the same type and value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These assertions use `==` which will perform type coercion. Hamcrest has `identicalTo($value)` which uses `===`, and I believe PHPUnit has `assertSame($expected, $actual)` which does the same.

```
self::assertSame(false, $dao->getUser(-2));
```

**Update:** In answer to your comment, "It can be NULL or an object":

```
$user = $dao->getUser(-2);
self::assertTrue($user === null || is_object($user));
```

Using Hamcrest assertions is a little more expressive, especially in the event of a failure:

```
assertThat($dao->getUser(-2), anyOf(objectValue(), nullValue()));
```

Comment: Thanks. MAybe you can help me on a philosophical problem as well dealing with this... What is the point of assertFalse, assertTrue, assertNull, etc if they do type coercion?

Comment: @KyleWpppd I'm still arguing that they are type safe and that it's a bug if $this->assertFalse(null); doesn't result in a failed test :)

Comment: You're right it does. What's hanging me up is the issue of how to assert that my result is not false. It  can be `NULL` or an object. But `FALSE` means there was a problem with the query.

Comment: @David Harkness - Thank you. I was wondering if there is a stylistic issue, but I guess having it work is more important than having it pretty. =)

Comment: @KyleWpppd - The main problem with using `assertTrue()` and `assertFalse()` is that the failure message is worthless: "Expected true but was false". You can always pass a description such as `self::assertTrue('user or null', ...);`

Answer (score 8):

Execute the comparison yourself, and use the strict type operator.

```
$this->assertTrue(false !== null);
```

http://php.net/operators.comparison

Answer (score 1):

@David is right with assertSame (+1), it will do === strict comparison for you.

---

But let me ask you:

Which version of phpunit are you using?

**This assertion:**

```
$this->assertFalse(null);
```

**should produce and error!**

### Sample Code:

```
<?php

class mepTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testFalseNull() {
        $this->assertFalse(null);
    }

    public function testNullFalse() {
        $this->assertNull(false);
   }
}
```

### Results in:

```
phpunit mepTest.php

PHPUnit 3.5.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

FF

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.00Mb

There were 2 failures:

1) mepTest::testFalseNull
Failed asserting that <null> is false.

/home/.../mepTest.php:6

2) mepTest::testNullFalse
Failed asserting that <boolean:false> is null.

/home/.../mepTest.php:10

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 2.
```

Comment: I'll have to look in about an hour or so. I think it is 3.5, but I will confirm.